# Entity Framework Core: how to sum across groups after groupby

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a `GroupBy` method and subsequent sum for each group. I would like then to take the sum *across* groups, but none of 10000 examples I looked at show how to do it.

Let

```
_context.BookSales
   .GroupBy(f => new {f.date, f.author, f.revenue, f.tax })
   .Where(a => a.key.author == "paulo coelho")
   .Select(g => new {
                    date = g.Key,
                    revenue = g.Sum(r => r.revenue)
                    tax = g.Sum(r => r.tax)
                    })
   .ToListAsync()
```

This will return a table of revenue and tax for each of the dates.

Now I need to do a simple sum for *both* revenue and tax *across* dates. How would I do it?

Comment: I should've written better: I have two columns I sum: g.Sum(r=> r.revenue) and g.Sum(r=>r.tax) for example. How would I sum both of these columns across the group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another `Sum` call at the end of the call stack:

```
var total = await _context.BookSales
   .GroupBy(f => new {f.date, f.author, f.revenue })
   .Where(a => a.key.author == "paulo coelho")
   .Select(g => new {
                    date = g.Key,
                    revenue = g.Sum(r => r.revenue)
                    })
   .ToListAsync()
   .Sum(x => x.revenue);
```

Or, if you need both, just split the data into two variables:

```
var sales = await _context.BookSales
   .GroupBy(f => new {f.date, f.author, f.revenue })
   .Where(a => a.key.author == "paulo coelho")
   .Select(g => new {
                    date = g.Key,
                    revenue = g.Sum(r => r.revenue)
                    })
   .ToListAsync();
var total = sales
   .Sum(x => x.revenue);
```

**UPD:**

If you have two separate sums, you'll have to have two separate variables for them. To not repeat the query to the data storage, you would want to do something like this:

```
var sales = await _context.BookSales
   .GroupBy(f => new {f.date, f.author, f.revenue })
   .Where(a => a.key.author == "paulo coelho")
   .Select(g => new {
                    date = g.Key,
                    revenue = g.Sum(r => r.revenue),
                    tax = g.Sum(r => r.tax),
                    })
   .ToListAsync();
var totalRevenue = sales
   .Sum(x => x.revenue);
var totalTax = sales
   .Sum(x => x.tax);
```

If you want a one-liner, you would probably be able to achieve this by using a more complex `Aggregate()` call, something like this (here I assume your values have type `decimal`, hence the `M` specifier after numbers):

```
var totals = (await _context.BookSales
   .GroupBy(f => new {f.date, f.author, f.revenue })
   .Where(a => a.key.author == "paulo coelho")
   .Select(g => new {
                    date = g.Key,
                    revenue = g.Sum(r => r.revenue),
                    tax = g.Sum(r => r.tax),
                    })
   .ToListAsync())
   .Aggregate((Revenue: 0.0M, Tax: 0.0M), (sums, next) => (Revenue: sums.Revenue + next.revenue, Tax: sums.Tax + next.tax ));

// Usage
Console.WriteLine("Totals: Revenue: {0}, Tax: {1}", totals.Revenue, totals.Tax);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WJDPfN

Comment: Oh sorry, I should've written better: I have two columns I sum: g.Sum(r=> r.revenue) and g.Sum(r=>r.tax) for example. How would I sum both of these columns across the group?

Comment: The easiest you can do is to create two separate variables for the sums. I'll add an update to my post.